# trying to calculate running time of a Controller action but getting wrong numbers - what's wrong with my code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### edit 2

if you stumble across this, I guess this was working corrreclty. Very surprised at the performance redis was giving me

---

I am writing a small after_filter called page_view to calculate the time an action takes in my 3.2.19 Rails app. It creates a @start_time in a before_filter in application_controller   and subtract out the current time in the after_filter. I don't need perfect accuracy but my response is being calculated as .5 milliseconds which is definitely not accurate (have to do a call to redis).

I have included the relevent fragments below. Any idea what is not working correctly?

```
class ApiItemsController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :page_view, only: :get_list
  ....
end  


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_start_time
  def set_start_time
    @start_time=DateTime.current.to_f
  end

  def page_view
    @now=DateTime.current.to_f
    @running_time=@now - @start_time
    PageView.create! running_time: @running_time.to_s 
  end
```

Results:

```
| 13043 | 0.014310121536254883    # MIGHT BE ACCURATE                                                               
| 13044 | 0.0005099773406982422                                                                   
| 13045 | 0.0005731582641601562                                                                   
| 13046 | 0.013282060623168945                                                                    
| 13047 | 0.0014388561248779297                                                                   
| 13048 | 0.000701904296875                                                                   
| 13049 | 0.0005688667297363281
```

### edit 1

so just hitting refresh, I get this record:

```
| 13054 | 0.0006530284881591797 36.0.1985.125
```

which would be .65 milliseconds for the action to run. Looking through the server logs, I get :

```
Completed 200 OK in 15.1ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)
```

which is a factor of 25 times greater. I wish it ran in .65 milliseconds - perhaps I'm being a total numskull and misreading these. Or is there perhaps a way to get what Rails has calculated as the response time which it obvisouly does since it's in the logs?

Comment: Why you think its not accurate

Comment: i love the # MIGHT BE ACCURATE      :)

Comment: Are you running this in production or on your local machine? Also if everything is on a single box it is possible it really is that fast.

Comment: well, I added why I think it's inaccurate in the first edit. Seems like the factor of 25 is too great. Really not needing perfect accuracy but just estimate. It would seem like Rails is already computing this for us - let me look...

Comment: What are you looking at from the logs? It shows view renders in 0.1ms which sounds about right, rounded from 0.65. Don't forget, the total (15.1ms) includes AR (your `PageView.create`) at an additional 12.3ms.

Comment: maybe I'm being an idiot (very likely) but the times coming back from the DateTime call are in seconds such that the 0.00065 is 0.65 milliseconds or siginificantly slower than the AR call. Why would an after_filter be run before an AR call is returned? thx for any help, really just looking for approximations but ...

Comment: it's because your after_filter runs the AR call after you've calculated the time at the beginning of that method call, *not* after the AR call within that method. Try adding another running time calc after the AR call in your `page_view` method: `logger.debug DateTime.current.to_f - @start_time`

Comment: hmm... so you're right Damien. I guess redis locally is THAT fast. I'm just really surprised.

Comment: Redis is just THAT fast :) It's all stored in memory, that's why (similar to memcache).